# Erro PostgreSQL: "ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "endereco""

Tags: sql, postgresql

criei a tabela Endereço e Cliente,como segue o sql:

```
CREATE TABLE ENDERECO(
Logradouro VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
CEP VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Numero INT NOT NULL,
Complemento VARCHAR(50),
Cidade VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
Bairro VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (Logradouro,CEP,Numero))


CREATE TABLE CLIENTE(
CPF INT NOT NULL,
Nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
TelefoneMovel VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
TelefoneFixo VARCHAR(25),
PRIMARY KEY (CPF))
```

Depois fui criar a tabela EndereçoCliente e deu esse erro

> **ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "endereco"

Segue a tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE ENDERECOCLIENTE(
ELogradouro VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
ECEP VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
ENumero INT NOT NULL,
CCPFCliente INT NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (ELogradouro,ECEP,ENumero,CCPFCliente),

FOREIGN KEY (ELogradouro) REFERENCES ENDERECO(Logradouro),
FOREIGN KEY (ECEP) REFERENCES ENDERECO(CEP),
FOREIGN KEY (ENumero) REFERENCES ENDERECO(Numero),
FOREIGN KEY (CCPFCliente) REFERENCES CLIENTE(CPF))
```

O que pode ser? Sendo que todas as colunas são unicas e chave primaria?

Answer (score 1):

As entidades `CLIENTE` e `ENDEREÇO` se relacionam.

A cardinalidade desse relacionamento é de `n:n`, ou seja, um `CLIENTE` pode possuir *nenhum* ou *vários* `ENDEREÇOS` cadastrados, e em um mesmo `ENDEREÇO`, podem residir *nenhum* ou *vários* `CLIENTES` diferentes.

Para se representar relacionamentos de cardinalidade `n:n` em bancos de dados relacionais usa-se uma *tabela de relacionamento*.

Sugiro que a sua tabela de `CLIENTES` possua uma `chave primária` simples, baseada em um `identificador único`:

```
CREATE TABLE TB_ENDERECO
(
    id_endereco INT NOT NULL,
    Logradouro VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    CEP VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Numero INT NOT NULL,
    Complemento VARCHAR(50),
    Cidade VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    Bairro VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (id_endereco)
);
```

Usar o `CPF` do cliente como a `chave primária` é uma boa quando seus `CLIENTES` se tratam de pessoas físicas:

```
CREATE TABLE TB_CLIENTE
(
    CPF VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
    Nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    TelefoneMovel VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    TelefoneFixo VARCHAR(25),

    PRIMARY KEY (CPF)
);
```

Assim sendo, sua `tabela de relacionamentos` ficaria assim:

```
CREATE TABLE RL_ENDERECO_CLIENTE
(
    CPF VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
    id_endereco INTEGER NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (CPF,id_endereco),

    FOREIGN KEY (id_endereco) REFERENCES TB_ENDERECO (id_endereco),
    FOREIGN KEY (CPF) REFERENCES TB_CLIENTE (CPF)
);
```

O que possilita a cardinalidade `n:n` desejada:

```
--
-- EXEMPLO #1) JOAO E MARIA RESIDEM NO MESMO ENDERECO EM SAO PAULO:
--

-- CLIENTE
INSERT INTO TB_CLIENTE( CPF, Nome, TelefoneMovel, TelefoneFixo ) VALUES ( '12345678900', 'JOAO SILVA', '981-1234', '555-1234' );
INSERT INTO TB_CLIENTE( CPF, Nome, TelefoneMovel, TelefoneFixo ) VALUES ( '00011122299', 'MARIA SILVA', '981-0000', '555-1234' );

-- ENDERECO
INSERT INTO TB_ENDERECO ( id_endereco, Logradouro, CEP, Numero, Complemento, Cidade, Bairro ) VALUES ( 1, '', '', 123, '', 'SAO PAULO - SP', '' );

-- RELACIONAMENTOS
INSERT INTO RL_ENDERECO_CLIENTE ( CPF, id_endereco ) VALUES ( '12345678900', 1 );
INSERT INTO RL_ENDERECO_CLIENTE ( CPF, id_endereco ) VALUES ( '00011122299', 1 );

--
-- EXEMPLO #2) CLIENTE "MADALENA" POSSUI 2 ENDERECOS EM "BRASILIA-DF" E EM "PORTO ALEGRE-RS":
--

-- CLIENTE
INSERT INTO TB_CLIENTE( CPF, Nome, TelefoneMovel, TelefoneFixo ) VALUES ( '99988877700', 'MADALENA SANTOS', '981-2323', '555-0000' );

-- ENDERECOS
INSERT INTO TB_ENDERECO ( id_endereco, Logradouro, CEP, Numero, Complemento, Cidade, Bairro ) VALUES ( 2, '', '', 321, '', 'BRASILIA - DF', '' );
INSERT INTO TB_ENDERECO ( id_endereco, Logradouro, CEP, Numero, Complemento, Cidade, Bairro ) VALUES ( 3, '', '', 171, '', 'PORTO ALEGRE - RS', '' );

-- RELACIONAMENTOS
INSERT INTO RL_ENDERECO_CLIENTE ( CPF, id_endereco ) VALUES ( '99988877700', 2 );
INSERT INTO RL_ENDERECO_CLIENTE ( CPF, id_endereco ) VALUES ( '99988877700', 3 );
```

Veja um exemplo funcionando no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/da0d1/1).

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE ENDERECOCLIENTE(
ELogradouro VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
ECEP VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
ENumero INT NOT NULL,
CCPFCliente INT NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (ELogradouro,ECEP,ENumero,CCPFCliente),

FOREIGN KEY (EEndereco) REFERENCES ENDERECO(Logradouro,CEP,Numero),
FOREIGN KEY (CCPFCliente) REFERENCES CLIENTE(CPF))
```

A FK deve "bater" com a respectiva PK.
Eu reveria seu padrão de nomenclatura.